# symmetrical weight painting can't let me paint center vertices of a mesh with mirror modifier and armature modifier

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones, weight-painting

I know how to do symmetrical weight painting on a mesh with mirror modifier and armature modifier, but this setting prevents me from weight painting center vertices properly.

my mesh is like 1st picture. It has center vertices (Location X 0).
but when I weight paint it, center vertices only have right side bone weight like 2nd picture, but it should be like bottom right value of 2nd picture because those vertices needs to be deformed by both left and right side bones. Is there anyway to do it? I need to use python script to archive this?

[image]

[image]